# How to write a procedure in Latex?

Tags: algorithms

I want to write a procedure in latex. I know the algorithmic package. But I want my function should not come with a name **Algorithm 1 Func_name**.

I want this.

```
Func_name(parameter)
{
   statement 1;
   statement 2;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a minimal code example of what you've tried (MWE).

Comment: The [listings](https://ctan.org/pkg/listings) package might be what you're after, especially if you have a specific programming language in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `algpseudocode.sty` from `algorithmicx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Function{Func\_name}{parameter}
      \State statement 1
      \State statement 2    
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```